# UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute() not working on .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I use `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` to redirect the user to an error page if there is a problem with the application.

If an Error occurs in my application for example Code 500, I am not redirected to "/Home/Error".
If I call it manually "/Home/Error" is ok!

Here is my code, where is the error?

```cs
        public IActionResult Error(string code)
        {
            return View(new ErrorModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier, ErrorStatusCode = code });
        }



public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSiteOfflineMiddleware(); 

            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?code={0}");

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication(); 
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSession(); // Aggiungi Supporto Sessioni

            // Dependency Injection Option per leggere Localizzazione File Resources delle lingue
            var localizationOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;
            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "products",
                    pattern: "{codLanguage}/shop/{id}/{nameProduct}",
                    new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Detail" });

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "catalog",
                    pattern: "/shop",
                    new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Index" });

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });


            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await Task.CompletedTask;
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6717), as Tratcher mentioned,UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute is for status code responses without bodies (e.g empty 404).And for the code like 500,you can use  UseExceptionHandler.

If you want to redirect to the url "/Home/Error" when the status code is 500, you can do like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
           app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error", "?code={0}");
```