# How to display custom 403 error page in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to use `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` in order to capture both **403** and **404** errors. However, 403 errors are re-executed to the 404 error page instead.

I'm not entirely sure about the cause and a lot of documentation I've found online refers to all sorts of other ASP.NET (Core) MVC versions. Below is my `Program.cs`. Is there a middleware or handler for http 403 errors?

Please let me know if you spot other coding mistakes here, as I'm fairly new to MVC Core.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");
    app.UseHsts();
}

FileExtensionContentTypeProvider fileProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
fileProvider.Mappings[".asc"] = "text/plain";

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { ContentTypeProvider = fileProvider });
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Not sure if you may have come across this post in your search https://stackoverflow.com/a/62127423/5233410

Comment: And you would normally want your error handling middleware to be added very early in the pipeline so your issue may be a route conflict.

Comment: At some point, I moved that below `UseStaticFiles` and don't remember why. There must have been some issue I have encountered. But moving it to the top also doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` doesn't detect the `403`, because it's not a `403` when it comes back up through that middleware. It's a `302` and therefore outside of the range `400-600`.  You get 404 may because the access denied path does not exist in your project.

Comment: Which authentication schema do you use? If you use Identity, you can configure `OnRedirectToAccessDenied` event.

Comment: @Rena I don't use any authentication. Do you have a suggestion?